# What is the meaning of $x \in [0,1]$ and $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: notation, convex-analysis, gamma-function, interval-arithmetic

Apologies if this is an obvious question.

I am asking mostly to make sure that my assumptions are correct.

I find this notation in many Wikipedia articles without any definition, for example, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition).

I am assuming that it doesn't mean $x$ is $0$ or $1$.

Am I correct that it is refering to a [mathematical interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)).

To give context, I am trying to understand the [Gautschi's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality#Statement) where $s \in [0,1]$ which I am assuming means that $s$ can be any real number such that $0 < s < 1$

Comment: $x \in [0, 1]$ means that $x$ is between $0$ and $1$, *inclusive*.  $x \in (0, 1)$ means that $x$ is between $0$ and $1$, *exclusive*.  Keep in mind any other possible restrictions on $x$ (for instance, whether $x$ is an integer, a rational, a real, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  For some reason, this notation is not mentioned in the WIkipedia aticle on intervals.

Comment: It may help to be familiar with the terms "open interval" and "closed interval."  I would, for example, interpret the condition on $s$ in that Wikipedia article as "$s$ falls in the open interval between $0$ and $1$."

Comment: P.S. you might encounter some people writing $]0,1[$ to mean $(0,1)$.  I think this is common in Europe; I don't see it often but I do occasionally.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology

Comment: Thanks.  I am clear on the meaning of open and closed intervals.  :-)  I wasn't 100% sure that the notation meant that.  Thanks to everyone for your clear explanations!  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman This notation is quite often used when dealing with real numbers & functions such as continuity, differentiability, etc., e.g., in Wikipedia's [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) article, the third paragraph starts with "More precisely, if $f$ is a [continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) on the [closed interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the [open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology) $(a,b)$, $\ldots$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct about it being an interval. 
So basically as the number of real numbers between 2 real numbers is infinite we denote the set of real number between the number a and b as an interval. 
The interval are of 3 types:

Open interval: It's a set of numbers between a and b, but the numbers a and b are excluded from the set. It is denoted by (a,b).

Closed interval: It's a set of numbers between a and b, including the numbers a and b. It is denoted as [a,b].

Half open and half closed: Here one of the number is included and other is not. Examples are [a,b) - here a is included but b isn't and in (a,b] b is included and a isn't.

In your question $x \in [0,1] \Rightarrow 0 \leq x \leq 1.$ 
And $x \in (0,1) \Rightarrow 0<x<1.$